# Java relative path to file

Tags: java, jsf, properties, path, relative-path

I am building a JSF 2.2 project in Netbeans 7.4 (Windows 7 64bit) and one of my beans need to use a properties file located to the directory `"/NetBeansProjects/projectName/web/WEB-INF/file.properties"` while the bean that needs it is on the `"/NetBeansProjects/projectName/src/java/packageName/bean.java"`. If I use an absolute path everything works like a charm but when I try to use a relative path it can not find the file. I tried to use every possible variation of `"../../../web/WEB-INF/file.properties"` but it just doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ExternalContext.getResourceAsStream()` to pass context-relative path

This should work:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
prop.load(externalContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/file.properties"));
```

Comment: When I try to copy exactly what you have written it doesn't find the class "externalContext" so when I use "ExternalContext" I am still having a problem because it is not a static method. Then when I try to use "new ExternalContext" it cannot find the method because it is an abstract class. I am using JEE 7.

Comment: @SpyrosNonServiam and of course you need to catch/throw `IOException`